# div height calc(100% - 50px) not working

Tags: css

https://codepen.io/joshuajazleung/pen/EbbgBN

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x200" alt="">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio animi harum impedit ex esse labore, placeat, tempore sapiente nisi cupiditate fugiat soluta ullam dicta ducimus accusamus tenetur consequuntur nesciunt earum!</div>
  </div>
</div>

.outer {
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  height: calc(100% - 60px);
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  top: -100px;
}
```

since .inner is moved to top a little bit, to reduce .outer overall space, I use

```
height: calc(100% - 50px); // my logic is that it's div's height minus 50px
```

But it's not working, wondering why?

Comment: You are required to post your markup here, not a codepen. [mcve]

Answer (score 10):

```
.outer {
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}
```

Try to change `100%` => `100vh`

Answer (score 3):

This won't work because the html and body elements don't span the full height by default. You're then setting a `height: calc(100% - 50px);` of something inside of that... To simplify it, just set `height: 100%` and you'll notice it isn't doing what you want.

You could set the height on the body and html to 100% as well, or you could try using 100vh instead of 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Not really clear what you are after, but if you use a `height` setting which contains percentage values, the *parent element* of that element needs to have a defined `height` definition in order have a reference for the percentage amount. In your case, that's the `body`, whose parent again is the `html` element, so you should add this CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XzzNbN